# Highcharts: Change color of Pie Chart section without slice animation

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization, pie-chart

Consider the following scenario:

1. I have the following fiddle of pie chart with already sliced sections.
   https://jsfiddle.net/amrutaJgtp/j2t0gdjt/4/

   ```
   series: [{
       data: [
           {
           name: 'Jan',
           y: 29.9,
           sliced:true
           },
       {
           name: 'Feb',
           y: 71.5,
           sliced:true

           },
       {
           name: 'Mar',
           y: 106.4,
           sliced:true

           },
       {
           name: 'Apr',
           y: 100,
           sliced:true

       }
       ],
       slicedOffset:20
   }]
   ```
2. On clicking/selecting any section (any number of times), I want to toggle the color of the section between the selection color and the original color
3. But I don't the sections to be restored to there original (0,0) position. That is they should remain sliced on click/select

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use [`point.events.unselect`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.point.events.unselect) and call there [`point.slice(true)`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.slice). Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/j2t0gdjt/9/

```
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            states: {
                select: {
                    color: '#ff0000'
                }
            },
            point:{
                events:{
                    unselect: function(event) {
                        this.slice(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the click event to select first, and then make sure it is sliced after ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2t0gdjt/7/)):

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        point:{
            events:{
                click: function(event) {
                    this.select(!this.selected, true);
                    this.slice(true);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This approach unfortunately doesn't work very well if not using the accumulated select. It might be better to find an approach where you manage to disable the slice event followed by a select event.